# Error importing bean definitions inside jar file

Tags: java, xml, spring, ant

I have two project. One is Project-A which contains database operations java codes and spring bean definition xml files. The structure is:

[image]

`resources/base` is source folder and `configure` is a package inside that source folder.
`base-definitions.xml` loads remaining xml files `[dao-service-definitions.xml and transaction-definition.xml]` like following.

**base-definitions.xml**

```
<import resource="classpath:configure/dao-service-definitions.xml"/>    
<import resource="classpath:configure/transaction-definition.xml"/>
```

Then I built jar file of that project including spring bean definiton files using Ant. I used `zipfileset` to set xml files directory inside jar file. The structure is same as above picture. `resources\base\configure\[xml files]`

**build.xml**

```
<zipfileset dir="../resources/base/configure" includes="*.*" prefix="resources/base/configure" />
```

In the another Project-B, I imported jar file and set classpath. Then import `base-definitions.xml` from Project-A into another xml in Project-B.

```
<import resource="classpath*:**/base-definitions.xml"/>
```

**Problem:**

The problem is `base-definitions.xml` is found but can't find definition files imported in that.

Extracted Errors:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath*:**/base-definitions.xml]
Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:configure/dao-service-definitions.xml]
class path resource [configure/dao-service-definitions.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your precious time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base-definitions.xml, I changed the

```
<import resource="classpath:configure/dao-service-definitions.xml"/>    
<import resource="classpath:configure/transaction-definition.xml"/>
```

to

```
<import resource="classpath:resources/base/configure/dao-service-definitions.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:resources/base/configure/transaction-definitions.xml"/>
```

and it is working now. I found out that, as Project-A is intended to use as jar file in another project, the structure must be absolute path.